# How to wait background task in Xamarin?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, asynchronous, background, task

I am trying to get a file from the device with Xamarin's file picker, and do some thing with that file. But, since the operation I'm trying to do is heavy, file picker freezes and waits for the task to be completed. So, I can't inform the user for the task, it just freezes. Simply I'm trying to run this operation on the background like:

1. select file
2. wait for file picker screen to close
3. Notify user for the task.
4. Do the operation with file.
   I tried to achieve this with 'await' but it didn't work.

Edit: I'm trying to do operation on the background without causing UI to freeze.

Here is my code

```
foreach (var file in pickResult)
                {
                    await Task.Run(async () =>
                   {
                       MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                       {
                           doSomethingWith(file.FullPath);
                       }
                       );
                   });
                }
```

I would be glad if you share your ideas to achieve this.

Comment: anything running within `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is explicitly NOT a background task

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var file in pickResult)
{
  tasks.Add(Task.Run(()=>doSomethingWith(file.FullPath)));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
//all done, you can update UI to indicate this.
```

Here we start the task for each file, then after the for-loop we wait asynchronously for all tasks will finish. And then we can update UI or something else.

Comment: This worked for me for files with large sizes, thanks. But this time, when I try to add files more than about 6-8, it throws this exception : : 'Index must be within the bounds of the List.
Parameter name: index'

Comment: Where you got such an exception? On which line of code? Try replace your doSomethingWith() with a dummy stub and check again - do you still will get exception?